# Hyperlinks in excel do not work

Tags: excel

I have a link in a cell converted to hyperlink. I looks just fine, but **if I click the link nothing happens**.

The excel file is a **xlsx** file running on **Excel:Mac 2011** (on Mac).

I also tried saving the file as **xls** but the problem persist.

I've made this capture which shows the dialog box for "Edit hyperlink". As you can see everything looks fine.

Link to the capture (sorry but I can't upload images yet..): [Capture](http://content.screencast.com/users/chefnelone/folders/Snagit/media/4f9e03f1-d325-449f-b0da-d92bf3afd59a/2012-03-29_12-19-32.png)

Comment: Can you confirm that hyperlinks from other sources work fine? I'm just thinking of possible security features. Have you tried something like Command-click or similar?

Comment: Not programing related, better suited to Super User

Comment: Jteagle: if by other sources you mean Word, yes they work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens to me often. What usually works is to double-click the cell, go to the end of the url and press space. Excel automagically converts it into a link you can follow. If you have many such links - you should look at what format your cells are in. Sometimes there are issues with links being in a cell that has been formatted "general". HTH

Comment: Double click didn't work. the cell format is set to general. Should I change this?

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution to this problem was to change the program defaults so that Internet Explorer is your default browser. From a Windows PC you can do this by:

1. Select Control Panel from the Start menu.
2. Click Programs.
3. Click Set Your Default Programs.
4. In the Programs list, select the browser you want to be your default.
5. Click Set this Program as Default.
6. Click OK.

However, I have also had this problem in the past because of a firewall issue.

For a Mac you would need to:

1. Open Safari.
2. Go to Safari > Preferences.
3. While on the General tab, select Internet Explorer as the browser you want to use as default from the drop down menu.
4. Click ok.

Where the problem is that the text won't show as a hyperlink add `http://` to the front of the cell.

Comment: And how does that fix the problem with the hyperlink in the Excel file? It is not a problem of browsing, or data traffic outside. The Excel itself does NOT treat the hyperlink as hyperlink, and therefore clicking on the cell does nothing, regardless of any external configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Frustrating that you can paste a hyperlink into a cell as part of a record and the hyperlink won't work.  I fixed it manually with these steps:

1. Right-mouse click on cell with non-working hyperlink
2. Select "Link"
3. Copy the URL in "Text to display"
4. Paste the URL into the blank "Address"
5. Click the "OK" button